# htaccess condition and rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

i have this link

http://localhost/fukhtaccess

and i want redirect the link to http://server.localhost/index.php with GET params.

this is my htaccess, but don't work and not possibile test with some error for debug (thanks apache foundation!!!)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTT_HOST} ^localhost$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} fukhtaccess

RewriteRule (.*) http://server.localhost/index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo: change `HTT_HOST` to `HTTP_HOST`.

Also, your second `RewriteCond` just complicates things unnecessarily. Do this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$
RewriteRule fukhtaccess http://server.localhost/index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

better, this work fine

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} fukhtaccess$ [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) http://server.localhost/index.php [QSA,L]
```